# What is the latest firebase-ui-auth for firebase auth 12.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

Not able to find anywhere the version used for firebase-auth 12.0.0. 
Github page shows the version upto 11.8.0.
Used 3.2.2 but showing error in android studio..
Not able to use com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0 because of firebase auth 11.8.0
Mixed versions error was coming.

Answer (score 0):

They have not updated the UI-Auth API. They usually run a few versions behind the Firebase Auth API. The latest UI version is 3.2.2 which corresponds to 11.8.0. You'll have to wait for sometime to for the UI Auth API to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [instructions in the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) for upgrading dependencies, add these to your dependencies, replacing 27.x.x with the version of the Support Libs you are using:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0"

implementation "com.android.support:design:27.x.x"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.x.x"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.x.x"
```